# Remove last n characters of string after the dot with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am using Autohotkey.

I have a string that looks like this `S523.WW.E.SIMA`. I want to remove the last few characters of the string after the dot (including the dot itself). So, after the removal, the string will look like `S523.WW.E`.

This may look like a simple question but I just cannot figure out using the available string functions in Autohotkey. How can this be done using Autohotkey? Thank you very much.

Comment: What were your attemps to solve your problem? Show us your code!

Comment: @MCL: I took the easy way out. I used `StringTrimRight` and simply removed the last 5 characters including the dot. Looks stupid, yes. Hope someone on StackOverflow can have a smarter solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter how "stupid" you believe your attemps may look. It's always good to show people what you've tried. This way, others can see that you've put effort into trying to solve it yourself. Also, others with the same problem will know how not do it, provided it's really that *stupid* ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Example 1 (last index of)

```
string := "S523.WW.E.SIMA"

LastDotPos := InStr(string,".",0,0)  ; get position of last occurrence of "."
result := SubStr(string,1,LastDotPos-1)  ; get substring from start to last dot

MsgBox %result%  ; display result
```

See [InStr](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Functions.htm#InStr)
See [SubStr](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Functions.htm#SubStr)

## Example 2 (StrSplit)

```
; Split it into the dot-separated parts,
; then join them again excluding the last part
parts := StrSplit(string, ".")
result := ""
Loop % parts.MaxIndex() - 1
{
        if(StrLen(result)) {
                result .= "."
        }
        result .= parts[A_Index]
}
```

## Example 3 (RegExMatch)

```
; Extract everything up until the last dot
RegExMatch(string, "(.*)\.", result)
msgbox % result1
```

## Example 4 (RegExReplace)

```
; RegExReplace to remove everything, starting with the last dot
result := RegExReplace(string, "\.[^\.]+$", "")
```

Comment: I've gathered some alternatives [here](http://pastebin.com/VBWCvqYZ). Maybe, you want to add them to your answer.

Comment: I thought about using RegExMatch() but I guess I got a "brainfart"... Anyway, nice examples! I will add them when I get access to a computer. Otherwise, feel free to edit this answer. :)