# Remove characters after a certain character in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am using Autohotkey.

I have this string variable `ABCDEF.XX`. I want to convert it to become `ABCDEF` by stripping away the characters after `.` including `.` itself.

```
inputVar:="ABCDEF.XX"
StringTrimRight, inputVar, inputVar, 3
```

What if I want the code to recognize the position of the dot . and remove the characters accordingly. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputVar:="ABCDEF.XX"
StringSplit, input_array, inputVar, .
MsgBox, %input_array1%
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm#Examples

or

```
FileName :="ABCDEF.XX"
SplitPath, FileName,,,,name_no_ext
MsgBox, %name_no_ext%
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplitPath.htm

or

[Remove last n characters of string after the dot with Autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840273/remove-last-n-characters-of-string-after-the-dot-with-autohotkey?rq=1)